# Error appearing when I try to access products

Tags: magento2, product, admin, error, shipping

When I try to access any of the products or add a new product in the admin panel I get an error usually along the lines of:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1318432854202
```

When checking in the var/report file I found the following error:

```
{"0":"Class ShipperHQ\\Shipper\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Source\\FreightClass does not exist","1":"#0 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Code\/Reader\/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('ShipperHQ\\\\Shipp...')\n#1 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Definition\/Runtime.php(44): Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Reader\\ClassReader->getConstructor('ShipperHQ\\\\Shipp...')\n#2 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php(48): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Definition\\Runtime->getParameters('ShipperHQ\\\\Shipp...')\n#3 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('ShipperHQ\\\\Shipp...', Array)\n#4 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Validator\/UniversalFactory.php(36): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create('ShipperHQ\\\\Shipp...', Array)\n#5 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-eav\/Model\/Entity\/Attribute\/AbstractAttribute.php(590): Magento\\Framework\\Validator\\UniversalFactory->create('ShipperHQ\\\\Shipp...')\n#6 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Eav\/Attribute\/Interceptor.php(1168): Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\AbstractAttribute->getSource()\n#7 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Eav.php(595): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Eav\\Attribute\\Interceptor->getSource()\n#8 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Eav.php(358): Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Eav->setupAttributeMeta(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Eav\\Attribute\\Interceptor), 'freight-shippin...', 0)\n#9 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Eav.php(331): Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Eav->getContainerChildren(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Eav\\Attribute\\Interceptor), 'freight-shippin...', 0)\n#10 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Eav.php(306): Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Eav->addContainerChildren(Array, Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Eav\\Attribute\\Interceptor), 'freight-shippin...', 0)\n#11 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Eav.php(266): Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Eav->getAttributesMeta(Array, 'freight-shippin...')\n#12 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/ProductDataProvider.php(73): Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Eav->modifyMeta(Array)\n#13 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php(310): Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\ProductDataProvider->getMeta()\n#14 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php(216): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata('product_form', Array, false)\n#15 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Generator\/UiComponent.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->create('product_form', NULL, Array)\n#16 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Generator\/UiComponent.php(97): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Data\\Structure), 'product_form', Array, Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor))\n#17 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/GeneratorPool.php(80): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Reader\\Context), Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\Context))\n#18 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php(344): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Reader\\Context), Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\Context))\n#19 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->generateElements()\n#20 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php(129): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->generateElements()\n#21 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Page\/Builder.php(55): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()\n#22 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php(65): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Page\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()\n#23 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php(254): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->build()\n#24 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php(876): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->build()\n#25 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->getBlock('menu')\n#26 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/Model\/View\/Result\/Page.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')\n#27 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\View\\Result\\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')\n#28 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/NewAction.php(71): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')\n#29 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/NewAction\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction->execute()\n#30 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php(107): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->execute()\n#31 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#32 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Backend\\App\\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#33 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#34 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php(143): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#35 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#36 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#37 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/NewAction\/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)\n#38 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(55): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#39 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#40 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#41 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#42 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/m2e\/ebay-amazon-magento2\/Plugin\/AbstractPlugin.php(34): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)\n#43
 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/m2e\/ebay-amazon-magento2\/Plugin\/HealthStatus\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController.php(42): Ess\\M2ePro\\Plugin\\AbstractPlugin->execute('dispatch', Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Array)\n#44 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Ess\\M2ePro\\Plugin\\HealthStatus\\Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#45 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/app\/code\/Infortis\/Cgen\/Plugin\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController.php(32): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#46 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Infortis\\Cgen\\Plugin\\Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#47 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#48 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#49 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#50 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#51 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#52 
\/var\/www\/vhosts\/***sitename***\/httpdocs\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#53 
{main}","url":"\/***username***\/catalog\/product\/new\/set\/4\/type\/simple\/key\/***keynumber***\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Could someone please explain to me what this error means and how to fix it?

As far as I know I removed the ShipperHQ module in order to use a different shipping rules module. If I've not removed it correctly could someone point me to how I can resolve this?

Comment: Did you run setup upgrade, di compile after remove?

Comment: in my case it's php bin/magento setup:di:compile

but yes I've run it since removing the module

Comment: Did you run php bin/magento setup:upgrade then php bin/magento setup:di:compile?

Comment: have you run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`?

Comment: Yes. Ran them several times since removing shipper HQ. Have also flushed the cache several times but still getting more-or-less the same error

Comment: is there any product attribute with that module?

Comment: I think that there were yes.

Comment: I think kunj is right. You have one product attribute which uses source model of shipperhq. Due to this you are getting error.

Comment: Yes you're right. I just deleted the attribute mentioned in the error and the products are displaying now. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That module has added below code to add product attribute so you need to remove the attribute(`freight_class`).

```
$catalogSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'freight_class', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'source' => 'ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\FreightClass',
            'input' => 'select',
            'label' => 'Freight Class',
            'global' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'is_configurable' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false
        ]);
```

Comment: Issue Now resolved. 

After going into Stores > Attributes > Products and deleting the offending "Freight" attribute I am no longer getting the error and the products are now displaying as usual.

Thanks to Kunj for all the help with resolving this and also to Sukamar Gorai for  his input

Comment: Welcome, happy to help you.